# c++ dynamicly change addresses in another process?

Tags: c++, security

Is it possible to change addresses in an application such that the app still works fine, but hacks (based on memory read/write) to this app don't? Maybe move the stack or something?

@update
I don't looking for randomization base address. I'm looking for method for changing addresses in running app such that app could still work but "hacks and bots" could not read this part of memory. ASLR isn't that what am I looking for (it's to easy to bypass)

Comment: what do you mean by movind the stack? You mean changing contents of stack? be more specific, question is not clear

Comment: Please include at least some additional information on things such as operating system, type of program, what you have tried searching, etc.
You may be looking for something like the "randomise base address" option in MSVC, or a technology such as `Address space layout randomization`

Comment: `what do you mean by movind the stack?` I mean some method to move entry the whole memory of app while it's running

Comment: Are you asking if there's some part of a process's memory that the program itself can access(can read from and write to) but not from an application on a different process using the os system API?

Comment: @PoiXen yup! That's exactly what I mean!

Comment: realloc() maybe be usefull for you. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/ or memcpy() http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

Comment: It's about self-reallocating, I'm looking for method to make reallocation in another process (something like antiBot-shield)

Answer (score 1):

Moving the stack will be very hard unless you can return all the way to main before you do it. Any variable passed as a reference or pointer to a varíable on the stack will not be allowed to move. And before you say "well, then I'll just allocate everything dynamically", now you have exactly the same problem - your HEAP is located in one place that is predictable (at least somewhat predictable), and thus can be modified. And of course, even if the heap isn't predictably placed, you can't just move it around at random during execution, since your code would rely on pointers and references to other data in the heap - and if you move that, you'd end up having to rearrange all those references. Finally, you will still have some register or memory location that is known or possible to calculate from some other value (e.g. the stack, some global data value, or something) that can be used to figure out where your data is.

My best suggestion would be to generate code in the heap, and use that to parallel calculate results that are used in your game.

Also, one way to avoid persistent locations is to run code in threads that are dynamically created and destroyed - that way, the stack is only in one place for a short period of time. But of course, it doesn't really stop someone who is skilled and determined to find a way around you protection. And with millions and millions of people in the world that have access to computers and are able to "break into things", you can't really rely on "security through obscurity" [making things complicated is not security].

The proper secure way is to perform all essential calculations on a server which holds the code, and the code isn't available to the public! However, for a FPS game, that's probably not realistic. For a poker game, it's very much realistic, especially if you are going to win money if you play well!